# Why is Azure "Unable to find the bot with the specified id" when attempting to open a Bot Service that very much exists in the Azure Portal?

Tags: azure, bots, azure-bot-service

I'm having a problem that I cannot find any information on anywhere on the Internet. I'm sharing an Azure directory with a number of my cohorts, and as such, any number of us might be working on a Resource in the Portal. However, when anyone creates a Bot Service, nobody else can access that Resource. Mind you, whoever creates the Bot Service can do whatever they want with it, but anyone else will see the error "Unable to find the bot with the specified id." (Written as is.) 
[image: This error message is shown in a prompt box (with an "OK" button) over a blank screen (in the context of the Portal window).]

We know that there's no problem with permissions, as everyone has full access to everything, and the problem only seems to be present for the Bot Service Resource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE**

All righty; so the problem's been solved. In order to avoid this error, I had to go to the dev.botframework.com website (where MSDN Bot Framework bots are hosted). Then, I went to the "Edit" section in the details panel on the bot's info page:

[image]

Next, I added the email addresses (corresponding to the appropriate Azure accounts) of the users who I wanted to have access to the bot to the Admin section's list of Owners:

[image]

And that's all there was to it. Would have been a lot simpler to figure out if there was a better error message! Jeeeeeeez.

Comment: Just an addendum: A coworker of mine was having trouble adding Owners to that Admin thing. Turns out it was the result of him including spaces after each delimiting comma. DON'T INCLUDE SPACES!

Comment: Lucky you. I started getting that error after I made the mistake of changing the BotId under App settings. NFI how to fix that one.